# ng-model does not update correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have a structure like this (much simplified):

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>Views and other stuff</div>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="item in $root.items track by $index">
        {{item.id}}
      </div>
    <div>
        Total value: {{totVal}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in my main controller I have defined $rootScope.items = [{id: 1,..},{id: 2,..},{id: 3,..},..] and in my other controller I have defined $scope.totVal = 0 and a watcher for the items array which updated the totVal when the items array changes;

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope, $scope) {
    // Are actually fetched from a service
    $rootScope.items = [
        {id: 1,..},
        {id: 2,..},
        ..
    ];
}])

.controller('MyCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope, $scope) {
    $rootScope.updateTotVal = function() {
        var totVal = 0;
        // calculations are done here
        // Is correct here when I console log after all calculations are complete
        console.log(totVal); 
        $scope.totVal = totVal;
    }

    $scope.totVal = 0;

    $rootScope.$watch('items', function() {
        $rootScope.updateTotVal();
    }, true);
}]);
```

The problem I have is that the totVal does not update in the view. When I console log the value it displays correctly in the console but it only updates in the view if I scroll the totVal div out of view and back again. Seems like an AngularJS bug in Chrome, but can't find any similar cases when i Google. It works fine in FireFox.

If I move the totVal before the ng-repeat it works and if I remove the ng-repeat it works (I rather don't change the structure of the html since it will be much work and make the design worse). I have also tried to move the totVal to the root scope without any success.

It's only the painting/rendering that fails, Batarang and console.log always gives me the updated value.

Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: `totVal` is set to 0 on every call to `updateTotVal`. I guess that's why you always see 0. Unless there is some code missing between the declaration of the variable and the `console.log`.

Comment: "// calculations" is the missing code...

Comment: link gave some good answers, which made my application better in it's structure. But the problem with the rendering still exists.
I have found out that if I put the value I want to render in a block elem it does not update until it is scrolled out of view and back again (only applies to Chrome). But if I put the value in a span or a floated elem it works. Must be a scope/rendering issue with Chrome and Angular...

Comment: please take your time to review the answers and choose a correct one (or add your solution, if different).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with Angular and Chrome. If I removed an ng-repeat that was before the totVal output it worked. It also worked if I put totVal higher up in the DOM structure or before the ng-repeat.
I think it has to do with the number of bindings and the complexity of the DOM, many nested DIV's breaks the binding somehow. I also noted that if I had many nested bootstrap classes like 'row' and 'col-xs-12' it also broke the binding. So it seems to be related to the browser rendering/painting the view (since scrolling the totVal out and back in to the view updated the value).

The main thing I learnt from this was to use smarter directives and try to simplify the DOM structure, especially if you use bootstrap.

Original:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>Views and other stuff</div>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in $root.items track by $index">
      {{item.id}}
    </div>
    <div>
      Total value: {{totVal}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Different changes that made it work properly:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>Views and other stuff</div>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div>
      Total value: {{totVal}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>Views and other stuff</div>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in $root.items track by $index">
      {{item.id}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Total value: {{totVal}}
  </div>
</div>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>Views and other stuff</div>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div>
      Total value: {{totVal}}
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in $root.items track by $index">
      {{item.id}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is exactly what you where looking for because I don't know your use case.
However, I achieved a working example, see it here [codepen](http://codepen.io/simonedavico/pen/ewkmz).

I refactored your code a bit, removing the extra controller and encapsulated `totVal` in a service. Also, I use the `controllerAs` syntax to make everything clearer.

The problem with your code is the fact that `totVal` is a primitive. Thus, when you assign it a new value, angular will not be able to update the reference. This is why you should **always have a dot in your model**!

Take a look at my code, you will se that I declared `totVal` as `var totVal = {val : 0}`. I simply update `val`, the reference is kept and the view is correctly updated.

```
.service('totVal', function(){
  var totVal = {val:0};

  this.computeTotVal = function(){
    //perform computations, I will just increment
    totVal.val++;
  }

  this.getTotVal = function() { return totVal; }
})
```

See also this [article](http://zcourts.com/2013/05/31/angularjs-if-you-dont-have-a-dot-youre-doing-it-wrong/).

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what I should do (and how it should be done). I will try this, but it will take me some time since it's a kinda big project to edit :s Will post back here when I know if it helped in this particular case. Thanks for the example :)

Comment: Glad it helped you. If you don't like to assign an object instead of a primitive (personally, I don't) a more refined solution is assigning `this.totVal = totVal` in the controller and call `totVal.getTotVal()` in the view. I updated the codepen example if you want to understand better what I am saying.

Comment: Ok, I have tested some of these things now. How do I fix this example?
http://plnkr.co/edit/YTx2ocNuRlnM6RHfTZH4?p=preview
I can't get the values to reset or interact with ng-model and select.

Comment: Let me take a look at it.

Comment: Ok, I corrected it. For dropdowns to behave correctly you have to use `ng-options`. [link to plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3sGchWokBt0EB9i1hekS?p=preview)

Comment: Ok, everythin but the reset seemed to work, but now the multiplier array was defined outside the service. Still don't get it right when I move everything into the service... The reset does not work, seems like it loses it's reference when you assign the value 0 to it. Any idéas how to fix the reset?
http://plnkr.co/edit/38QPxAfaXp64a8JPBJx9?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56750/discussion-between-link-and-kungwaz).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the culprit, but you definitely shouldn't use `$rootScope` for this.

As the doc states:

> $rootScope exists, but it can be used for evil

See here: https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#-rootscope-exists-but-it-can-be-used-for-evil

---

I would rewrite your code without it, when not necessary:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>Views and other stuff</div>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <!-- You also had an $root.items that didn't match any element here -->
    <div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
      {{item.id}}
    </div>
    <div>
      Total value: {{totVal}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in your controller you will bind your items, like this:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // Are actually fetched from a service
    $scope.items = [
        {id: 1,..},
        {id: 2,..},
        ..
    ];
}])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$rootScope','$scope', function($rootScope, $scope) {
    $scope.updateTotVal = function() {
        var totVal = 0;

        // calculations

        console.log(totVal); // Is correct here

        $scope.totVal = totVal;
    }

    $scope.totVal = 0;

    // Here $rootScope makes sense
    $rootScope.$watch('items', function() {
        $scope.updateTotVal();
    }, true);
}]);
```

**Edit:**
Also, everytime you instantiate your controller, you set `$rootScope.totalVal = 0`, eventually resetting it.
Maybe this is why you don't see the update?

Comment: But how do I share functions and variables between controllers if they all are in the controller scope?
I want to be able to access the updateTotVal from multiple controllers.

Comment: You usually use an injectable, like a `service` for example, which being a singleton will provided a consistent value whenever you'll inject it.